# Debugging SIGSEGV Java Runtime Fatal Error (PySpark on Python)

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, jvm

Hi so I'm trying to run a python scripts that uses pyspark. I have tried the script on my own machine and it works fine. But when I tried running it on an AWS instance with ubuntu 18.04 it gave a fetal error that has to do with java. I'm new to pyspark so I'm not sure if it was my installation of pyspark is the problem or java or python... I have looked at many posts that deal with similar problem but no luck so far (I have never dealt with such errors). I was not sure which part of the log file is important... so here is some of the log file:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007ff25e2c4ba3, pid=3614, tid=3956
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.9.1+1) (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04, mixed mode, tiered, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0xea8ba3]
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P %E" (or dumping to /home/ubuntu/recsys-challenge-2020-twitter/core.3614)
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-lts
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: -Xmx186g org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit --conf spark.executor.memory=186g --conf spark.driver.memory=186g --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=186g --conf spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled=True --conf spark.app.name=RunMF pyspark-shell

Host: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8259CL CPU @ 2.50GHz, 48 cores, 186G, Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Time: Sun Nov 22 20:51:43 2020 UTC elapsed time: 83.357052 seconds (0d 0h 1m 23s)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007fbef407d000):  JavaThread "stdout writer for python" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=3956, stack(0x00007fbe727ea000,0x00007fbe728eb000)]

Stack: [0x00007fbe727ea000,0x00007fbe728eb000],  sp=0x00007fbe728e9080,  free space=1020k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, A=aot compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0xea8ba3]
J 3779  jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V java.base@11.0.9.1 (0 bytes) @ 0x00007ff247cf4a85 [0x00007ff247cf49c0+0x00000000000000c5]
j  sun.misc.Unsafe.putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V+7 jdk.unsupported@11.0.9.1
j  org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform.putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V+6
j  org.apache.spark.unsafe.UnsafeAlignedOffset.putSize(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V+31
j  org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeExternalSorter.insertRecord(Ljava/lang/Object;JIJZ)V+126
J 15181 c1 org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeExternalRowSorter.insertRow(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/UnsafeRow;)V (76 bytes) @ 0x00007ff2422c82ac [0x00007ff2422c8100+0x00000000000001ac]
j  org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3.sort_addToSorter_0$(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3;)V+24
j  org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3.processNext()V+16
J 12389 c2 org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext()Z (31 bytes) @ 0x00007ff2483ff448 [0x00007ff2483fe9e0+0x0000000000000a68]
J 10105 c2 scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext()Z (10 bytes) @ 0x00007ff2481869d0 [0x00007ff2481869a0+0x0000000000000030]
j  org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.hasNext()Z+4
J 2705 c1 scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Lscala/collection/Iterator;Lscala/Function1;)V (6 bytes) @ 0x00007ff240d76084 [0x00007ff240d75d80+0x0000000000000304]
j  org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.foreach(Lscala/Function1;)V+2
j  org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(Lscala/collection/Iterator;Ljava/io/DataOutputStream;)V+8
j  org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(Ljava/io/DataOutputStream;)V+8
j  org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(Lorg/apache/spark/api/python/BasePythonRunner$WriterThread;)Ljava/lang/Object;+779
j  org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$Lambda$4987.apply()Ljava/lang/Object;+4
J 13596 c1 org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Lscala/Function0;)Ljava/lang/Object; (66 bytes) @ 0x00007ff241fa7ba4 [0x00007ff241fa7aa0+0x0000000000000104]
j  org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run()V+9
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x87f359]
V  [libjvm.so+0x87d49d]
V  [libjvm.so+0x926c7c]
V  [libjvm.so+0xe7b37f]
V  [libjvm.so+0xe77acf]
V  [libjvm.so+0xc1977e]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J 3779  jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V java.base@11.0.9.1 (0 bytes) @ 0x00007ff247cf4a0c [0x00007ff247cf49c0+0x000000000000004c]
j  sun.misc.Unsafe.putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V+7 jdk.unsupported@11.0.9.1
j  org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform.putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V+6
j  org.apache.spark.unsafe.UnsafeAlignedOffset.putSize(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V+31
j  org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeExternalSorter.insertRecord(Ljava/lang/Object;JIJZ)V+126
J 15181 c1 org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeExternalRowSorter.insertRow(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/UnsafeRow;)V (76 bytes) @ 0x00007ff2422c82ac [0x00007ff2422c8100+0x00000000000001ac]
j  org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3.sort_addToSorter_0$(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3;)V+24
j  org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3.processNext()V+16
J 12389 c2 org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext()Z (31 bytes) @ 0x00007ff2483ff448 [0x00007ff2483fe9e0+0x0000000000000a68]
J 10105 c2 scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext()Z (10 bytes) @ 0x00007ff2481869d0 [0x00007ff2481869a0+0x0000000000000030]
j  org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.hasNext()Z+4
J 2705 c1 scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Lscala/collection/Iterator;Lscala/Function1;)V (6 bytes) @ 0x00007ff240d76084 [0x00007ff240d75d80+0x0000000000000304]
j  org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil$AutoBatchedPickler.foreach(Lscala/Function1;)V+2
j  org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(Lscala/collection/Iterator;Ljava/io/DataOutputStream;)V+8
j  org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$2.writeIteratorToStream(Ljava/io/DataOutputStream;)V+8
j  org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.$anonfun$run$1(Lorg/apache/spark/api/python/BasePythonRunner$WriterThread;)Ljava/lang/Object;+779
j  org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread$$Lambda$4987.apply()Ljava/lang/Object;+4
J 13596 c1 org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Lscala/Function0;)Ljava/lang/Object; (66 bytes) @ 0x00007ff241fa7ba4 [0x00007ff241fa7aa0+0x0000000000000104]
j  org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$WriterThread.run()V+9
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x0000000000000804

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0 is NULL
RBX=0x00007fbef407d000 is a thread
RCX=0x0000000000000804 is an unknown value
RDX=0x00007ff25d8cc9f0: <offset 0x00000000004b09f0> in /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/server/libjvm.so at 0x00007ff25d41c000
RSP=0x00007fbe728e9080 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fbef407d000
RBP=0x00007fbe728e90b0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fbef407d000
RSI=0x00007fbe728e90c0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fbef407d000
RDI=0x00007fbef407d340 points into unknown readable memory: 60 3a 8d 5e f2 7f 00 00
R8 =0x0000000000000030 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0 is NULL
R10=0x00007ff247cf4a0c is at entry_point+76 in (nmethod*)0x00007ff247cf4810
R11=0x00007ff247cf49d8 is at entry_point+24 in (nmethod*)0x00007ff247cf4810
R12=0x0 is NULL
R13=0x0000000000000804 is an unknown value
R14=0x0000000000000030 is an unknown value
R15=0x00007fbef407d000 is a thread


Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x00007fbef407d000, RCX=0x0000000000000804, RDX=0x00007ff25d8cc9f0
RSP=0x00007fbe728e9080, RBP=0x00007fbe728e90b0, RSI=0x00007fbe728e90c0, RDI=0x00007fbef407d340
R8 =0x0000000000000030, R9 =0x0000000000000000, R10=0x00007ff247cf4a0c, R11=0x00007ff247cf49d8
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x0000000000000804, R14=0x0000000000000030, R15=0x00007fbef407d000
RIP=0x00007ff25e2c4ba3, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246, CSGSFS=0x002b000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000006
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007fbe728e9080)
0x00007fbe728e9080:   00007fbef407d000 00007fbef407d000
0x00007fbe728e9090:   00007fc1f66ab748 00007fc6b2ad5968
0x00007fbe728e90a0:   00007fbe728e9118 00007fbe728e91b8
0x00007fbe728e90b0:   00007fbe728e9100 00007ff247cf4a85 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007ff25e2c4ba3)
0x00007ff25e2c4aa3:   d8 00 00 00 a9 00 00 00 30 74 08 48 89 df e8 2a
0x00007ff25e2c4ab3:   a7 fc ff 4d 85 e4 c7 83 b8 03 00 00 06 00 00 00
0x00007ff25e2c4ac3:   0f 84 d3 00 00 00 41 f6 c4 01 0f 85 b5 00 00 00
0x00007ff25e2c4ad3:   4c 89 e7 ff 15 44 ce 60 00 48 85 c0 0f 84 b7 00
0x00007ff25e2c4ae3:   00 00 46 89 34 28 48 8b 9b f0 00 00 00 48 8b 43
0x00007ff25e2c4af3:   10 4c 8b 63 08 48 83 38 00 74 19 48 8b 73 28 4c
0x00007ff25e2c4b03:   89 e7 e8 d6 6d 55 ff 48 8b 7b 10 e8 7d 5e 55 ff
0x00007ff25e2c4b13:   48 8b 43 10 49 89 44 24 10 48 8b 43 18 48 8d 7d
0x00007ff25e2c4b23:   d8 49 89 44 24 18 48 8b 43 20 49 89 44 24 20 e8
0x00007ff25e2c4b33:   89 11 a6 ff 48 83 c4 10 5b 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 5d
0x00007ff25e2c4b43:   c3 0f 1f 40 00 f0 83 04 24 00 48 8d 05 0c 27 67
0x00007ff25e2c4b53:   00 83 38 01 0f 85 32 ff ff ff 48 8b 03 48 8d 15
0x00007ff25e2c4b63:   89 7e 60 ff 48 8b 40 28 48 39 d0 75 48 48 8b 83
0x00007ff25e2c4b73:   08 01 00 00 48 c1 e8 03 83 e0 01 e9 1a ff ff ff
0x00007ff25e2c4b83:   0f 1f 44 00 00 49 8d 7c 24 ff ff 15 85 cd 60 00
0x00007ff25e2c4b93:   48 85 c0 0f 85 49 ff ff ff c6 83 dc 03 00 00 01
0x00007ff25e2c4ba3:   45 89 75 00 c6 83 dc 03 00 00 00 e9 36 ff ff ff
0x00007ff25e2c4bb3:   0f 1f 44 00 00 48 89 df ff d0 84 c0 0f 84 ca fe
0x00007ff25e2c4bc3:   ff ff eb a9 66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 55 48 89
0x00007ff25e2c4bd3:   e5 41 55 41 54 53 48 8d 9f c0 fc ff ff 49 89 d4
0x00007ff25e2c4be3:   49 89 cd 48 83 ec 18 8b 83 d0 03 00 00 2d ab de
0x00007ff25e2c4bf3:   00 00 83 f8 01 76 0a 48 89 df 31 db e8 4c a1 fc
0x00007ff25e2c4c03:   ff 48 89 df 48 89 5d d8 e8 60 c5 ff ff 4d 85 e4
0x00007ff25e2c4c13:   0f 84 87 00 00 00 41 f6 c4 01 75 71 4c 89 e7 ff
0x00007ff25e2c4c23:   15 f8 cc 60 00 48 85 c0 74 73 46 8b 2c 28 48 8b
0x00007ff25e2c4c33:   9b f0 00 00 00 48 8b 43 10 4c 8b 63 08 48 83 38
0x00007ff25e2c4c43:   00 74 19 48 8b 73 28 4c 89 e7 e8 8e 6c 55 ff 48
0x00007ff25e2c4c53:   8b 7b 10 e8 35 5d 55 ff 48 8b 43 10 49 89 44 24
0x00007ff25e2c4c63:   10 48 8b 43 18 48 8d 7d d8 49 89 44 24 18 48 8b
0x00007ff25e2c4c73:   43 20 49 89 44 24 20 e8 41 10 a6 ff 48 83 c4 18
0x00007ff25e2c4c83:   44 89 e8 5b 41 5c 41 5d 5d c3 0f 1f 00 49 8d 7c
0x00007ff25e2c4c93:   24 ff ff 15 7d cc 60 00 48 85 c0 75 8d c6 83 dc 


Stack slot to memory mapping:
stack at sp + 0 slots: 0x00007fbef407d000 is a thread
stack at sp + 1 slots: 0x00007fbef407d000 is a thread
stack at sp + 2 slots: {method} {0x00007fc1f66ab748} 'putInt' '(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V' in 'jdk/internal/misc/Unsafe'
stack at sp + 3 slots: 0x00007fc6b2ad5968 is an oop: java.math.MutableBigInteger 
{0x00007fc6b2ad5968} - klass: 'java/math/MutableBigInteger'
stack at sp + 4 slots: 0x00007fbe728e9118 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fbef407d000
stack at sp + 5 slots: 0x00007fbe728e91b8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fbef407d000
stack at sp + 6 slots: 0x00007fbe728e9100 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fbef407d000
stack at sp + 7 slots: 0x00007ff247cf4a85 is at entry_point+197 in (nmethod*)0x00007ff247cf4810

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Threads class SMR info:
_java_thread_list=0x00007fbeec059b70, length=195, elements={
0x00007ff25801c000, 0x00007ff258263000, 0x00007ff258267800, 0x00007ff25827e800,
0x00007ff258281000, 0x00007ff258283000, 0x00007ff258285000, 0x00007ff258315000,
0x00007ff25831f000, 0x00007ff2597e5000, 0x00007ff2597ee800, 0x00007fc0e8009000,
0x00007fc0e4281800, 0x00007fc0e4289000, 0x00007fc0e428a000, 0x00007fc0e428b800,
0x00007fc0e428d000, 0x00007fc0e428e800, 0x00007fc0e4290800, 0x00007fc0e4292800,
0x00007fc0e4294000, 0x00007fc0e4296000, 0x00007fc0e4297800, 0x00007fc0e4299800,
0x00007fc0e429b000, 0x00007fc0e429d000, 0x00007fc0e429e800, 0x00007fc0e42a0800,
0x00007fc0e42a2000, 0x00007fc0e42a3800, 0x00007fc0e42a5800, 0x00007fc0e42a7800,
0x00007fc0e42a9000, 0x00007fc0e42ab000, 0x00007fc0e42ad000, 0x00007fc0e42ae800,
0x00007fc0e42b0800, 0x00007fc0e42b2000, 0x00007fc0e42b4000, 0x00007fc0e42b6000,
0x00007fc0e42b7800, 0x00007fc0e42b9800, 0x00007fc0e42bb800, 0x00007fc0e42bd000,
0x00007fc0e42bf000, 0x00007fc0e42c1000, 0x00007fc0e42c2800, 0x00007fc0e42c4800,
0x00007fc0e42c6000, 0x00007fc0e42c7800, 0x00007fc0e42c9800, 0x00007fc0e42cb800,
0x00007fc0e42cd000, 0x00007fc0e42cf000, 0x00007fc0e42d1000, 0x00007fc0e42d2800,
0x00007fc0e42d4800, 0x00007fc0e42d6000, 0x00007fc0e42d8000, 0x00007fc0e42da000,
0x00007fc0e42dc000, 0x00007fc0e431f800, 0x00007fc0e431d800, 0x00007fc0e431b800,
0x00007fc0e430e800, 0x00007fc0e430f800, 0x00007fc0e4316800, 0x00007fc0e4318800,
0x00007fc0e431a800, 0x00007fc0e4373000, 0x00007fc0e4391800, 0x00007fc0e43b0000,
0x00007fc0e43c4800, 0x00007fc0e44be800, 0x00007fc0e44bf000, 0x00007fc0e44c1000,
0x00007fc0e44c2800, 0x00007fc0e44c4800, 0x00007fc0e44c6000, 0x00007fc0e44c8000,
0x00007fc0e44ca000, 0x00007fbfd8001000, 0x00007fbfdc001000, 0x00007fc0e450d000,
0x00007fbfd4001000, 0x00007fbfc8001000, 0x00007fbfcc001000, 0x00007fc0e4517800,
0x00007fbfc0001000, 0x00007fbfb8001000, 0x00007fc0d4001800, 0x00007fbfb4007800,
0x00007fc0e4610800, 0x00007fc0e4611800, 0x00007fc0e4d03800, 0x00007fc0e4d56800,
0x00007fc0e4d6d800, 0x00007fc0e4d75000, 0x00007fc0e503b800, 0x00007fc0e503d800,
0x00007fc0e5046800, 0x00007fc0e5048800, 0x00007fbf8c025000, 0x00007fc0e550a000,
0x00007fc0e4d7e800, 0x00007fc1cc217000, 0x00007fc1ac1b0800, 0x00007fc1ac1b2000,
0x00007fc09001f000, 0x00007fc090020000, 0x00007fc090021800, 0x00007fc090023000,
0x00007fc090024800, 0x00007fc090026800, 0x00007fc090028800, 0x00007fc09002a800,
0x00007fc09002c000, 0x00007fc09002e000, 0x00007fc090030000, 0x00007fc090032000,
0x00007fc090034000, 0x00007fc090036000, 0x00007fc090037800, 0x00007fc090039800,
0x00007fc09003b800, 0x00007fc09003d800, 0x00007fc09003f800, 0x00007fc090041000,
0x00007fc090043000, 0x00007fc090044800, 0x00007fc090046800, 0x00007fc090048000,
0x00007fc09004a000, 0x00007fc09004b800, 0x00007fc1141d9000, 0x00007fc09004d800,
0x00007fc09004f800, 0x00007fc090051800, 0x00007fc090053800, 0x00007fc090055000,
0x00007fc090057000, 0x00007fc090059000, 0x00007fc09005b000, 0x00007fc09005c800,
0x00007fc09005e800, 0x00007fc090060800, 0x00007fc090062000, 0x00007fc090064000,
0x00007fc090066000, 0x00007fc090068000, 0x00007fc090069800, 0x00007fc09006b800,
0x00007fc09006d000, 0x00007fc09006f000, 0x00007fc090071000, 0x00007fc090073000,
0x00007fc090075000, 0x00007fc088005800, 0x00007fc08800a800, 0x00007fc08800c800,
0x00007fc08800e000, 0x00007fc048001000, 0x00007fc000002800, 0x00007fbe68003800,
0x00007fbe68005800, 0x00007fbe60002000, 0x00007fbe54001000, 0x00007fc1cc170800,
0x00007fc1ac2bf000, 0x00007fc1ac220000, 0x00007fc1ac221000, 0x00007fc1ac222000,
0x00007fc1ac223800, 0x00007fc110f52800, 0x00007fc11c3b3000, 0x00007fbf2806d800,
0x00007fbf28073000, 0x00007fbf28074000, 0x00007fbf28078000, 0x00007fbf28070800,
0x00007fbef0062000, 0x00007fbef0070800, 0x00007fbf2807d000, 0x00007fbf18052800,
0x00007fbf1805a800, 0x00007fbe64024000, 0x00007fbe64026000, 0x00007fbf44053000,
0x00007fbf44054800, 0x00007fbefc059000, 0x00007fbefc05b000, 0x00007fbef407d000,
0x00007fbef407e800, 0x00007fbeec056800, 0x00007fbeec058000
}

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00007ff25801c000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=3643, stack(0x00007ff25f6bc000,0x00007ff25f7bd000)]
  0x00007ff258263000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3650, stack(0x00007fc1f63e9000,0x00007fc1f64ea000)]
  0x00007ff258267800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3651, stack(0x00007fc1f62e8000,0x00007fc1f63e9000)]
  0x00007ff25827e800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3652, stack(0x00007fc1f5ed9000,0x00007fc1f5fda000)]
  0x00007ff258281000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3653, stack(0x00007fc1f5dd8000,0x00007fc1f5ed9000)]
  0x00007ff258283000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3654, stack(0x00007fc1f5cd7000,0x00007fc1f5dd8000)]
  0x00007ff258285000 JavaThread "Sweeper thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3655, stack(0x00007fc1f5bd6000,0x00007fc1f5cd7000)]
  0x00007ff258315000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3657, stack(0x00007fc1f59d4000,0x00007fc1f5ad5000)]
  0x00007ff25831f000 JavaThread "Common-Cleaner" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3659, stack(0x00007fc1f57d1000,0x00007fc1f58d2000)]
  0x00007ff2597e5000 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=3718, stack(0x00007fc1a8546000,0x00007fc1a8647000)]
  0x00007ff2597ee800 JavaThread "Thread-2" [_thread_in_native, id=3719, stack(0x00007fc1a8242000,0x00007fc1a8343000)]
  0x00007fc0e8009000 JavaThread "Thread-3" [_thread_blocked, id=3720, stack(0x00007fc1a8141000,0x00007fc1a8242000)]
  0x00007fc0e4281800 JavaThread "rpc-boss-3-1" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3721, stack(0x00007fc1a8ca3000,0x00007fc1a8da4000)]
  0x00007fc0e4289000 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3722, stack(0x00007fc1a8ba2000,0x00007fc1a8ca3000)]
  0x00007fc0e428a000 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3723, stack(0x00007fc1a8849000,0x00007fc1a894a000)]
  0x00007fc0e428b800 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3724, stack(0x00007fc1a8040000,0x00007fc1a8141000)]
  0x00007fc0e428d000 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3725, stack(0x00007fc0efeff000,0x00007fc0f0000000)]
  0x00007fc0e428e800 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3726, stack(0x00007fc0ef555000,0x00007fc0ef656000)]
  0x00007fc0e4290800 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3727, stack(0x00007fc0ef454000,0x00007fc0ef555000)]
  0x00007fc0e4292800 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3728, stack(0x00007fc0ef353000,0x00007fc0ef454000)]
  0x00007fc0e4294000 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3729, stack(0x00007fc0ef252000,0x00007fc0ef353000)]
  0x00007fc0e4296000 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-8" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3730, stack(0x00007fc0ef151000,0x00007fc0ef252000)]
  0x00007fc0e4297800 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-9" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3731, stack(0x00007fc0ef050000,0x00007fc0ef151000)]
  0x00007fc0e4299800 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-10" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3732, stack(0x00007fc0eef4f000,0x00007fc0ef050000)]
  0x00007fc0e429b000 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-11" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3733, stack(0x00007fc0eee4e000,0x00007fc0eef4f000)]
  0x00007fc0e429d000 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-12" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3734, stack(0x00007fc0eed4d000,0x00007fc0eee4e000)]
  0x00007fc0e429e800 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-13" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3735, stack(0x00007fc0eec4c000,0x00007fc0eed4d000)]
  0x00007fc0e42a0800 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-14" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3736, stack(0x00007fc0eeb4b000,0x00007fc0eec4c000)]
  0x00007fc0e42a2000 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-15" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3737, stack(0x00007fc0eea4a000,0x00007fc0eeb4b000)]
  0x00007fc0e42a3800 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-16" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3738, stack(0x00007fc0ee949000,0x00007fc0eea4a000)]
  0x00007fc0e42a5800 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-17" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3739, stack(0x00007fc0ee848000,0x00007fc0ee949000)]
  0x00007fc0e42a7800 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-18" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3740, stack(0x00007fc0ee747000,0x00007fc0ee848000)]
  0x00007fc0e42a9000 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-19" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3741, stack(0x00007fc0ee646000,0x00007fc0ee747000)]
  0x00007fc0e42ab000 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-20" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3742, stack(0x00007fc0ee545000,0x00007fc0ee646000)]
  0x00007fc0e42ad000 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-21" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3743, stack(0x00007fc0ee444000,0x00007fc0ee545000)]
  0x00007fc0e42ae800 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-22" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3744, stack(0x00007fc0ee343000,0x00007fc0ee444000)]
  0x00007fc0e42b0800 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-23" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3745, stack(0x00007fc0ee242000,0x00007fc0ee343000)]
  0x00007fc0e42b2000 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-24" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3746, stack(0x00007fc0ee141000,0x00007fc0ee242000)]
  0x00007fc0e42b4000 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-25" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3747, stack(0x00007fc0ee040000,0x00007fc0ee141000)]
  0x00007fc0e42b6000 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-26" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3748, stack(0x00007fc0edf3f000,0x00007fc0ee040000)]
  0x00007fc0e42b7800 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-27" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3749, stack(0x00007fc0ede3e000,0x00007fc0edf3f000)]
  0x00007fc0e42b9800 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-28" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3750, stack(0x00007fc0edd3d000,0x00007fc0ede3e000)]
  0x00007fc0e42bb800 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-29" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3751, stack(0x00007fc0edc3c000,0x00007fc0edd3d000)]
  0x00007fc0e42bd000 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-30" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3752, stack(0x00007fc0edb3b000,0x00007fc0edc3c000)]
  0x00007fc0e42bf000 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-31" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3753, stack(0x00007fc0eda3a000,0x00007fc0edb3b000)]
  0x00007fc0e42c1000 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-32" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3754, stack(0x00007fc0ed939000,0x00007fc0eda3a000)]
  0x00007fc0e42c2800 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-33" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3755, stack(0x00007fc0ed838000,0x00007fc0ed939000)]
  0x00007fc0e42c4800 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-34" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3756, stack(0x00007fc0ed737000,0x00007fc0ed838000)]
  0x00007fc0e42c6000 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-35" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3757, stack(0x00007fc0ed636000,0x00007fc0ed737000)]
  0x00007fc0e42c7800 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-36" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3758, stack(0x00007fc0ed535000,0x00007fc0ed636000)]
  0x00007fc0e42c9800 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-37" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3759, stack(0x00007fc0ed434000,0x00007fc0ed535000)]
  0x00007fc0e42cb800 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-38" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3760, stack(0x00007fc0ed333000,0x00007fc0ed434000)]
  0x00007fc0e42cd000 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-39" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3761, stack(0x00007fc0ed232000,0x00007fc0ed333000)]
  0x00007fc0e42cf000 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-40" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3762, stack(0x00007fc0ed131000,0x00007fc0ed232000)]
  0x00007fc0e42d1000 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-41" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3763, stack(0x00007fc0ed030000,0x00007fc0ed131000)]
  0x00007fc0e42d2800 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-42" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3764, stack(0x00007fc0ecf2f000,0x00007fc0ed030000)]
  0x00007fc0e42d4800 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-43" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3765, stack(0x00007fc0ece2e000,0x00007fc0ecf2f000)]
  0x00007fc0e42d6000 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-44" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3766, stack(0x00007fc0ecd2d000,0x00007fc0ece2e000)]
  0x00007fc0e42d8000 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-45" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3767, stack(0x00007fc0ecc2c000,0x00007fc0ecd2d000)]
  0x00007fc0e42da000 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-46" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3768, stack(0x00007fc0ecb2b000,0x00007fc0ecc2c000)]
  0x00007fc0e42dc000 JavaThread "dispatcher-event-loop-47" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3769, stack(0x00007fc0eca2a000,0x00007fc0ecb2b000)]
  0x00007fc0e431f800 JavaThread "map-output-dispatcher-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3770, stack(0x00007fc0ec929000,0x00007fc0eca2a000)]
  0x00007fc0e431d800 JavaThread "map-output-dispatcher-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3771, stack(0x00007fc0ec828000,0x00007fc0ec929000)]
  0x00007fc0e431b800 JavaThread "map-output-dispatcher-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3772, stack(0x00007fc0ec727000,0x00007fc0ec828000)]
  0x00007fc0e430e800 JavaThread "map-output-dispatcher-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3773, stack(0x00007fc0ec626000,0x00007fc0ec727000)]
  0x00007fc0e430f800 JavaThread "map-output-dispatcher-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3774, stack(0x00007fc0ec525000,0x00007fc0ec626000)]
  0x00007fc0e4316800 JavaThread "map-output-dispatcher-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3775, stack(0x00007fc0ec424000,0x00007fc0ec525000)]
  0x00007fc0e4318800 JavaThread "map-output-dispatcher-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3776, stack(0x00007fc0ec323000,0x00007fc0ec424000)]
  0x00007fc0e431a800 JavaThread "map-output-dispatcher-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3777, stack(0x00007fc0ec222000,0x00007fc0ec323000)]
  0x00007fc0e4373000 JavaThread "dispatcher-BlockManagerMaster" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3778, stack(0x00007fc0ec121000,0x00007fc0ec222000)]
  0x00007fc0e4391800 JavaThread "dispatcher-BlockManagerEndpoint1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3779, stack(0x00007fc0ec020000,0x00007fc0ec121000)]
  0x00007fc0e43b0000 JavaThread "RemoteBlock-temp-file-clean-thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3780, stack(0x00007fc00bcff000,0x00007fc00be00000)]
  0x00007fc0e43c4800 JavaThread "refresh progress" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3781, stack(0x00007fc00bbfe000,0x00007fc00bcff000)]
```

Also I do apologize about the "tags" for the question, I was not sure what the source of the problem is so feel free to tell me if something is unrelated so I can remove it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm working on an ec2 instance on AWS so I'm trying to solve it as fast as possible

Answer (score 1):

There's not much that you can do. SIGSEGV means that the JVM or code running in the context of the JVM accessed memory it is not allowed to access. Therefore, the JVM crashed. But it tries to be helpful and to give some indication where the problem might be:

```
V  [libjvm.so+0xea8ba3]
```

This tells us that the JVM crashed in libjvm.so which is a core part of the JVM. But this does not necessarily mean that the fault is in the JVM. Let's have a look at the stack trace below:

```
V  [libjvm.so+0xea8ba3]
J 3779  jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V java.base@11.0.9.1 (0 bytes) @ 0x00007ff247cf4a85 [0x00007ff247cf49c0+0x00000000000000c5]
j  sun.misc.Unsafe.putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V+7 jdk.unsupported@11.0.9.1
j  org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform.putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V+6
```

This tells us that Apache Spark calls into `sun.misc.Unsafe` from the method `org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform.putInt(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)` (last two lines). `Unsafe` allows direct memory access without any safety checks performed by the JVM, hence the name ([detailed explanation](https://www.baeldung.com/java-unsafe)). So if Apache Spark does an unsafe call and the JVM crashes as a consequence, it is pretty safe to assume that Apache Spark does something wrong there.

I recommend reporting it to the Apache Spark project. Because no matter whether you made a mistake or Apache Spark, neither should crash the JVM by trying to access memory it shouldn't access.